# Selectpicker filters broke by Leaflet

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, leaflet, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am generating a map with leaflet package on my webapp, after I execute my code once, all my filters are broke and I get this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function #2357

The map is generating it owns html page with packages and I think the problem comes from a package not imported on this section :

[image]

I want to add those two lines in Leaflet header but I don't know where I can change the head imports.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Any ideas ? Thank you

Comment: It woul be helpful, when you tell us the name of your programm / generator

Comment: I'm using the Leaflet package to generate a map into a container div in my web application (Flask/HTML/JS)